# Apache kafta ACL authentication using cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka

Is there a way to do Apache kafta ACL authentication using cassandra ? I have not seen any example on this so far.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: There's no way. But i can't understand how you want to connect kafka with cassandra. You can't connect kafka directly with cassandra. You need an application between kafka and cassandra. Usually: A stream processor like spark or flink. If you want to use a ACL in this application, you can use Kafka ACL in Zookeeper. Here's wiki entry about this: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Authorization+Command+Line+Interface

Comment: i meant How can i do ACL on application level using cassandra? what u are refering is command line but i want to use it dynamically from my application

Comment: You can set permissions with regular CQL Queries. Here's a nice introduction: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra